# Running custom commands with VS Code and CMake Tools

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, mpi

I am using VS Code with the CMake Tools extension, and I would like to run a simple MPI program. Everything compiles just fine, and I can run my code in the terminal using

```
mpiexec -n 6 "path-to-my-workspace\build\my-executable.exe"
```

However, I would like to set things up so that this gets executed automatically when I press Control + Shift + P > "CMake: Run Without Debugging" (or Shift F5).

I read in the [CMake Tools documentation](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/debugging.html) that I could create new launch targets in a launch.json file. However, the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) states that

> The launch.json file is used to configure the debugger in Visual Studio Code.

I want this for debug, but also for release. Should I still use a launch.json file? I had the same problem in the past when I needed to pass arguments to my main function. What is the right way to do that in VS Code with CMake Tools?

Comment: you may be interested in the "tip" stated at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like two cases of terminology-related confusion.

1. In VS Code, there are actions to "Run Code" and "Run Without Debugging". You can find more about the distinction between the two [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64534535/11107541). In a nutshell, "Run Code" runs the program inside a debugger program (like gdb), and and "Run Without Debugging" also runs the program, but doesn' run it inside a debugger program.
2. The two most common build modes are "debug" and "release", where debug includes debugging symbols that enable running in a debugger, and release does not and instead is built with more optimizations. VS Code can run both types of builds without debugging, and can run debug builds in a debugger. For release builds, it can only run outside a debugger.

You specify that you only care to run outside a debugger.

To answer your question "*Should I still use a launch.json file?*", **yes, you can** still use a launch.json file.

For running with a debugger, note that you can use [the `cmake.debugConfig` setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings), which will integrate with the features that CMake Tools provides for debugging targets.

Also, [note](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode):

> Tip: The Run action is always available, but not all debugger extensions support 'Run'. In this case, 'Run' will be the same as 'Debug'.

Another note: If the program you wanted to run *wasn't* a build output of your project, then you would instead probably want to be using [`tasks.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).

If you like docs, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md.