# Difference between Run Code and Run without Debugging in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am a newbie in cpp programming and use visual studio code, I don't understand what is the difference between Ctrl + Alt + N(To run code) and Ctrl + F5(Run without Debugging).

[image]

[image]

Comment: `run without debugging` is actually running your code normally. When you run it *with* debugging it actually means that the program that you've written actually runs inside of another "debugger" program that keeps track of memory - so if you do something wrong with memory it can tell you about it -  and can pause the program for you at certain lines of the code if you want it to.

Comment: MSVS in my opion kinda wants to do the thinking for you, so it annoyingly decides to put you in debugging mode by default, which will slow compilation and slow the run-time of your program. I'd go into debugging mode only when you actually want to do debugging.

Comment: If you're a beginner then you probably just want to use the debugger mode when checking for memory leaks or segmentation faults.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+N</kbd> (Run Code) is a shortcut provided by the "Code Runner" extension you've installed. It runs the code **without** debugging.

<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> (Debug: Start without Debugging) is a VS Code default shortcut. Despite its name, it actually runs the C++ code **with** debugging. This is because according to the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode):

> Tip: The Run action is always available, but not all debugger extensions support 'Run'. In this case, 'Run' will be the same as 'Debug'.

Apparently the [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) does not support "Run", so `Ctrl + F5` will launch a debug session instead.

Comment: I also wonder what extensions would support 'Run".

Answer (score 9):

## CTRL-F5 is just F5

It's probably worth noting since this is tagged `c++` that `CTRL-F5`, *run without debugging* actually runs ***with*** debugging as of August 23rd 2021. That's in-spec for the app [according to these docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode), *"Tip: The Run action is always available, but not all debugger extensions support 'Run'. In this case, 'Run' will be the same as 'Debug'."*

## SHIFT-F5 is no Panacea

`SHIFT-F5` from the standard C++ extension, by contrast, does run without debugging, but runs a target set by its own mechanism, not the current launch configuration used by `F5` and `CTRL-F5`. Since it bypasses the `launch.json` launch configurations, it does not let you change the location of the current working directory for your app or pass-in command line arguments to it.

Comment: The "Run is same as debug" is driving me nuts. I don't want to start the debugger every time I run my program. Do you know how to revert to the old behavior? I just want to compile and run a single c/c++ file without any complex extensions. Shift+F5 does nothing (and is not even defined as a keybind) and Ctrl+F5 just runs the debugger like F5.

Comment: If what you want is that simple, can't you just execute a one-liner in the terminal to build and run your single file C++ program? VS Code probably lets you bind the execution of your one liner to a key press.
`SHIFT-F5` is defined by the standard C++ extension maintained by Microsoft: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools.

Comment: I can, but I still want the CTRL-F5 functionality

Comment: "run without debugging actually runs with debugging as of August 23rd 2021". Thanks for explaining, because this surprise change happened while returning to an unfinished dev container. This type of change is non-intuitive and I wish they prompted before enabling this "feature".

Comment: Then what's the official way of doing Release Builds?

Comment: Shift-F5 on my VSCode is for Stop Debugging.